# How can I fetch data from database order by name and that name value?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database

```
INSERT INTO `telex` (`id`, `chart_date`, `week_no`, `task`, `completion`, `user`) VALUES
(4, '2018-07-03 00:00:00', 26, 2, 0, 'sarath'),
(6, '2018-07-03 00:00:00', 26, 8, 100, 'sarath'),
(7, '2018-07-03 00:00:00', 26, 25, 100, 'sakthi'),
(8, '2018-07-03 00:00:00', 26, 3, 100, ''),
(9, '2018-07-03 00:00:00', 26, 2, 0, 'admin'),
(10, '2018-07-03 00:00:00', 26, 3, 0, ''),
(13, '2018-06-26 00:00:00', 25, 4, 100, 'sarath'),
(14, '2018-06-26 00:00:00', 25, 20, 100, 'sakthi'),
(19, '2018-06-19 00:00:00', 24, 3, 100, 'sarath'),
(20, '2018-06-19 00:00:00', 24, 3, 100, ''),
(21, '2018-06-19 00:00:00', 24, 2, 100, 'admin'),
(22, '2018-06-19 00:00:00', 24, 2, 0, 'admin'),
(23, '2018-06-19 00:00:00', 24, 14, 100, 'sakthi'),
(26, '2018-06-12 00:00:00', 23, 7, 100, 'sarath'),
(27, '2018-06-12 00:00:00', 23, 18, 100, 'sakthi'),
(28, '2018-06-05 00:00:00', 22, 3, 100, 'sarath'),
(32, '2018-06-05 00:00:00', 22, 19, 100, 'sakthi'),
(33, '2018-05-29 00:00:00', 21, 9, 100, 'sarath'),
(34, '2018-05-29 00:00:00', 21, 2, 0, 'sakthi'),
(35, '2018-05-29 00:00:00', 21, 2, 0, ''),
(36, '2018-05-29 00:00:00', 21, 42, 100, 'sakthi'),
(37, '2018-05-29 00:00:00', 21, 4, 0, 'admin'),
(38, '2018-05-22 00:00:00', 20, 6, 100, 'sarath'),
(40, '2018-05-29 00:00:00', 21, 5, 100, ''),
(42, '2018-05-22 00:00:00', 20, 4, 100, ''),
(44, '2018-05-22 00:00:00', 20, 2, 100, 'admin'),
(45, '2018-05-22 00:00:00', 20, 2, 0, ''),
(46, '2018-05-22 00:00:00', 20, 45, 100, 'sakthi'),
(48, '2018-05-15 00:00:00', 19, 8, 100, 'sarath'),
(52, '2018-05-15 00:00:00', 19, 25, 100, 'sakthi'),
(55, '2018-05-15 00:00:00', 19, 5, 100, ''),
(60, '2018-05-08 00:00:00', 18, 6, 100, 'sarath'),
(62, '2018-05-08 00:00:00', 18, 5, 100, ''),
(63, '2018-05-08 00:00:00', 18, 34, 100, 'sakthi'),
(65, '2018-05-01 00:00:00', 17, 22, 100, 'sakthi'),
(68, '2018-04-24 00:00:00', 16, 25, 100, 'sakthi'),
(69, '2018-04-17 00:00:00', 15, 2, 0, 'sakthi'),
(75, '2018-04-17 00:00:00', 15, 2, 0, ''),
(76, '2018-04-17 00:00:00', 15, 4, 0, 'admin'),
(77, '2018-04-17 00:00:00', 15, 30, 100, 'sakthi'),
(79, '2018-04-10 00:00:00', 14, 9, 100, 'sarath'),
(82, '2018-04-10 00:00:00', 14, 2, 100, 'vijay'),
(83, '2018-04-10 00:00:00', 14, 2, 100, ''),
(86, '2018-04-10 00:00:00', 14, 34, 100, 'sakthi'),
(87, '2018-04-10 00:00:00', 14, 2, 0, 'vijay'),
(88, '2018-04-03 00:00:00', 13, 11, 100, 'sarath'),
(89, '2018-04-03 00:00:00', 13, 3, 10, ''),
(90, '2018-04-10 00:00:00', 14, 9, 0, ''),
(91, '2018-04-03 00:00:00', 13, 17, 100, 'sakthi'),
(92, '2018-03-27 00:00:00', 12, 2, 100, ''),
(93, '2018-03-27 00:00:00', 12, 2, 0, ''),
```

Notice that `week_no` is the third column and `task` is the forth.

I want to fetch the data order by week and that week task like

```
['salkthi',1,2,3,3,3,3,34,6,5,6,],
['vijay',1,2,3,6,4,5,9,7]
```

I did fetch week by order using **SELECT DISTINCT**. 
How can I fetch user name by **SELECT DISTINCT** and get that particular user task by order by week.

I tried that with foreach but I was not able to fetch that properly

```
$outpy=array();
$result_name = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT user FROM telex");
while($rs = $result_name->fetch_assoc()) {
    $outpy[]= $rs["user"];
    $outpy[0]='NoName'; 
}
foreach ($outpy as $value) {
   $name[] = $value;
if($name[0]==$value){
    $result_name = $conn->query("SELECT task FROM telex WHERE user='$value'");
}
}
```

If you have any new idea please help me because I'm new to IT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right then you can use `ORDER BY`. Like that:

```
SELECT task FROM telex WHERE user='$user' ORDER BY week_no ASC
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

BTW you can do it in single query without making first query for users:

```
SELECT task, user FROM telex ORDER BY week_no ASC
```

And then process result in PHP:

```
$result = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['user']])) { 
        $result[$row['user']] = [];
    }
    $result[$row['user']][] = $row['task'];
}
```

So you'll get an array like that:

```
[
    'sarath' => [1,2,3,4],
    'admin' => [1,2,3,4]
]
```

Comment: @kealaxshan you filter them by `WHERE` clause, don't you?